# Импорт базы ФИАС в Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, ruby, dbf

Пишу микросервис, для работы с фиасом, проблемы настигли на первых шагах, подключил гем [fias](https://github.com/evilmartians/fias) попытался сделать импорт из DBF в Postgresql, при помощи рэйк таска описанного гемом. В итоге получаю такой стэктрэйс:

```
vagrant@fsc-dev:~/fiasco/tmp/fias$ bundle exec rake fias:create_tables fias:import
DATABASE_URL=postgres://localhost/fiasco_db FIAS_PATH=$(pwd) 
(in /home/vagrant/fiasco)
rake aborted!
DBF::Column::NameError: column name cannot be empty
/var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/dbf-3.0.3/lib/dbf/column.rb:152:in `validate_name'
/var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/dbf-3.0.3/lib/dbf/column.rb:41:in `initialize'
/var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/dbf-3.0.3/lib/dbf/table.rb:216:in `new'
/var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/dbf-3.0.3/lib/dbf/table.rb:216:in `build_columns'
/var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/dbf-3.0.3/lib/dbf/table.rb:198:in `columns'
/var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/fias-1.0.1/lib/fias/import/tables.rb:40:in `columns_for'
/var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/fias-1.0.1/lib/fias/import/tables.rb:32:in `create_table'
/var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/fias-1.0.1/lib/fias/import/tables.rb:15:in `block in create'
/var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/fias-1.0.1/lib/fias/import/tables.rb:13:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/fias-1.0.1/lib/fias/import/tables.rb:13:in `create'
/var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/fias-1.0.1/tasks/db.rake:9:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/fias-1.0.1/tasks/db.rake:50:in `within_connection'
/var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/fias-1.0.1/tasks/db.rake:8:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => fias:create_tables
```

Времени маловато, чего греха таить: не хочется разбирать все в нули - искал готовое решение, подумал может все просто и я чего-то явного не улавливаю, не долго думая написал сюда.

Comment: Не парьтесь с этим dbf. Есть же фиас xml.

Comment: ruby какой версии?

Comment: @Invision ruby 2.2.0

Comment: а схема где? =)

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ если имеется в виду xsd, то на официальном сайте http://fias.nalog.ru/Public/DownloadPage.aspx

Comment: @Sergey нет, схема базы данных, у вас же на миграции обламываемся задача

Answer (score 2):

Вероятно в каком-то из dbf не заполнено поле name.
Покажите результат выполнения:

```
bundle exec rake fias:create_tables fias:import DATABASE_URL=postgres://localhost/fiasco_db --trace
```

Удалите старый архив

```
rm -r tmp/fias tmp/fias/fias_dbf.rar
```

Скачайте новый. Он довольно часто обновляется.

```
bundle exec rake fias:download | xargs wget
```

У меня процесс выполнения идёт полным ходом.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]